# How to print tor external ip in terminal

Tags: command-line, ip, tor

I want to print external ip when the system is connected to tor proxy. ie. tor exit node IP. I have found plenty of ways, by using online services. But i have found that most of the servers are sending empty response or not reachable since its blocking tor (i think so). Is there any dedicated servers for that? is there any way by using tor control port?

NOTE: sites like ifconfig.me, ipfy , ..etc Fails most of the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an `alias` like this:

```
alias tconfig='curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 https://check.torproject.org |& grep -Po "(?<=strong>)[\d\.]+(?=</strong)"'
```

then whenever you want run `tconfig` to get your exit node ip.

You can also use other tools but they can't say what circuit you are connecting to.

Comment: Thank you it worked. can i do the same thing in python too? using beautifulsoup library?

Comment: @Susmith you can do it using any language or library that's up to you ;)

Comment: @Susmith Be aware that [your Tor client changes its exit node every ten minutes or so](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChangePaths), so any **new** TCP connections after ten minutes probably use a new IP.

Comment: On macOS and likely a different version of grep, 2.5.1, the grep command didn't seem to work. Here's my alternative solution
`alias tconfig='curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 https://check.torproject.org |& grep "<strong>" | grep -Eo "(\d|\.)+"'`